# Unrecognized selector sent to instance - RN firebase messaging

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've installed firebase into my react native app to use messaging push notifications. It works fine in debug mode, but when I run the release app on an iOS device it crashes in main.m on the UIApplicationMain line with the exception:

`__NSCFString *   "-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

When I comment out the firebase calls from my RN app it works fine.

I have installed:

```
"react-native": "^0.61.5",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^13.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^13.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^13.0.1",

COCOAPODS: 1.11.2
Firebase/Messaging (8.9.1)
```

Not sure how to fix this error, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of describing the code where the crash happens, please edit your question to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code that any of us can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).